# GLOBAL data per HTTP/Session request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, global

**QUESTION:**

**Is there any way to create a variable storage in per session/http request? The variable must be globally accessible and different per HTTP request/connection/session, and need not be passed from function to function.**

For example (just to illustrate):

```
setVariableThatCanBeAccessedByThisHTTPRequestOnly( 'a string data' );
```

Anything should work, but I'd prefer to stay away from passing it from function to function.

```
//I'm trying to get rid of passing req parameter to all custom functions.
//I'd like to store it in a variable somehow, that it can be accessed globally, but only within that session/request.
exports.functionName = function( req, res ) {

   customFunctionThatRequiresReq( req );

};
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTIONS**

I've been playing with node.js lately, and have a little concern about its GLOBAL scope. Let's say we have a server.js file:

```
username = ""; //Global scope
```

Then when a connection is established and the server receives a request, it will do the followings:

```
username = selectUsernameWithConditions(); //This will return a username
```

My question is: If 2 different computers are sending the requests to the server, will the value of `username` be independently different? I mean, does the `username` when the first request is processed different from the `username` when the second request is processed, or they are just one variable and will be overridden?

If they are overridden, what is the best way to store data and make them globally accessible within that requests and/or session only? For example, the following code:

```
username = selectUsernameWithConditions(); //This will return a username
```

Will assign `username` differently for different requests and not overriding each other.

Comment: Perhaps `var usernames = {}; usernames[requestID] = selectUsernameWithConditions();` then you can get the username associated with a particular request.

Comment: Hi RobG. That's actually a good idea. But what is the variable that will ALWAYS be distinctive from request to request to be used as `requestID`? It would be painful if it is the same somehow between 2 different requests/sessions.

Comment: Maybe attach it to the request, e.g. `req.username = selectUsernameWithConditions()`?

Comment: Hi candu. If I attach it to the request, can I access it outside of the function that handles the request? For example: `exports.index = function( req, res ) { /* My functions have to be within this scope to access req */ }`.

Comment: @cuzmAZN: You would have to pass the `req` (or just the `username`) to any function that was called from within your route handler if you wanted it to have access to the `username`).

Comment: @go-oleg: That was why I did originally. I am finding a way to escape from it if there is any. It's just a little messy passing the `request` all around from functions to functions.

Comment: @cuzmAZN: Yea, you can pass just the `username` or some sort of object that represents the "session data" for the request that different functions might need.

Comment: @go-leg: Thanks! I did it originally. Say, whenever I need to connect to database (self-made function, which I do quite a lot of times within 1 function), I have to pass the `req`, like: `connectToDatabase( req, database )`. Repeating that is messy. I would like to store that `req` in some variable so I can access it (because it won't change anyway) without passing it around.

Comment: potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35381981/14266931

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access request context anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556637/access-request-context-anywhere)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with some caveats.
You're looking for a module called [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/continuation-local-storage).
This allows you to keep arbitrary data for the remainder of callbacks for the current request, and access it in a global fashion.
I wrote a blog post about it [here](https://datahero.com/blog/2014/05/22/node-js-preserving-data-across-async-callbacks/). But the gist is this:

1. Install cls: `npm install --save continuation-local-storage`
2. Create a namespace for your app (at the top of the main file for your app)

   ```
   var createNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').createNamespace, 
       namespace = createNamespace('myAppNamespace');
   ```
3. Create a middleware that runs downstream functions in the cls (continuation-local-storage) namespace

   ```
   var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace,
       namespace = getNamespace('myAppNamespace'),

   app.use(function(req, res, next) {    
     // wrap the events from request and response
     namespace.bindEmitter(req);
     namespace.bindEmitter(res);

     // run following middleware in the scope of the namespace we created
     namespace.run(function() {
       namespace.set(‘foo’, 'a string data');
       next();
     });
   });
   ```
4. Since you ran `next` within `namespace.run`, any downstream function can access data in the namespace

   ```
   var getNamespace = require('continuation-local-storage').getNamespace,
       namespace = getNamespace('myAppNamespace');

   // Some downstream function that doesn't have access to req...
   function doSomething() {
     var myData = namespace.get('foo');
     // myData will be 'a string data'
   }
   ```
5. There is the caveat that certain modules can "lose" the context created by cls. This means that when you go to lookup 'foo' on the namespace, it won't have it. There are a few ways to deal with this, namely using another module like [cls-redis](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cls-redis), cls-q, or binding to the namespace.

Comment: This is the closest to what I am looking for, though a little complicated! Thanks so much for the enlightenment!

Comment: Let me know if you run into any trouble or have any questions. This *is* cutting edge node, and I have a post coming out in a few days talking about it. That being said, it's safe to use in production right now.

Answer (score 1):

Per request, I think what you're after could be done with ordinary closures. For example, you'd define your custom functions in module that takes a `req` argument:

*util_funcs.js:*

```
module.exports = function( req ){
  return {
    customFunctionThatRequiresReq: function(){ console.info( req ) },
    otherFunctionThatRequiresReq:  function(){ console.log( req ) }
  };
};
```

Then wherever you depend on those functions (presumably some middleware elsewhere in the application), you can just require them in context:

```
var someMiddleWare = function( req, res, next ){

  var utils = require( 'util_funcs.js' )( req );

  utils.customFunctionThatRequiresReq();
  utils.otherFunctionThatRequiresReq();

};
```

This allows you to avoid littering your function args with `req`, and no dubious globals.

Comment: honestly this is the best answer. and so elegant. this is exactly what the doctor ordered. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right to understood your question you can try to make global variable in node js which can stored username

you can use global array with unique id

suppose user1 hit the http request therefore you store like this in node js

```
if(!username)
   username = [];

if(!uniqId)
   uniqId = 0;
uniqId++;

username[uniqId] = 'xyz';
```

similar like this it is working

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I've thought of that, but the problem is how do you know which uniqueID that HTTP request is on? You have to have a varible telling the server which ID it is, and it's the same story all over again, we have to pass around that uniqueID. :-/. Should there be any build-in session ID that's unique per request?

Comment: can your node js script run continuously such as process

Answer (score 0):

You can an unstable feature: nodejs [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html)

I do this on top of my head so read the docs and figure out really how it works ;)

Create a middleware high up in the hierarchy that will create a domain and run the remaining request handlers in the context of that domain:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var domain = domain.create();
  domain.req = req;
  domain.run(next);
});
```

Then anywhere in your handlers, you can access the current request with:

```
var req = process.domain.req;
```

Again, read the docs, I'm really not sure about all this but this is one approach!

Comment: Hi. This may be the closest answer I've seen. It's unstable though. But I do learn a lot from this answer. Let me take a few days and see what else is brought up.

Comment: Good catch, but on some requests domains don't have time to initialize.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using a cookies?
set the cookie to the browser and then everytime there is a request, you would know the user by its cookie..
you may use 'cookie-parser' node library.

Comment: if you're giving an answer, explain with a little example; else, write it as a comment.