# Accessing information of authenticated user in request scope using express

Tags: express, typeorm

I'm using Express with TypeORM and currently I got stuck in the following situation:

Before inserting or updating a record, I always want to set the username to the current record to persist the information who last updated this record.

With TypeORM, this can easily be done by using subscribers:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class Subscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
    beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
        const entity = event.entity;
        if(entity instanceof Base) {
            entity.lastUpdatedBy = 'username'; // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

The user is known after he was successfully authenticated:

```
@Put('/entity')
public updateEntity(@CurrentUser({required: true}) user: User, @Body enity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
    Log.info('User successfully authenticated: ' + user)
    return this.manager.update(entity);
}
```

**My question is: What is the simpliest way to store and access user information in a request scope?**

What I found out so far:

1. The following stackoverflow-post seems to be related, but the
   solutions sounds like a overhead for me ([GLOBAL data per HTTP/Session request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151952/global-data-per-http-session-request))
2. I also could append the user information in the updateEntity method, but then I have to explicitly all the time.

Is there any other option?

Comment: did you solve the problem? May i ask if you can provide a more deatailed answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following npm package to save the user in my request scope: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked.

This package did not work for me since async/await seems not to be supported: continuation-local-storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the atttribute **data** of type *any* of the **SaveOptions**.

```
@Put('/entity')
public updateEntity(@CurrentUser({required: true}) user: User, @Body enity: Entity): Promise<Entity> {
    Log.info('User successfully authenticated: ' + user)
    return this.manager.update(entity, {data: user});
}
```

And then, you can use the data in Subscriber with:

```
event.queryRunner.data
```